# Cannot import pandas through PyCharm:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

Appreciate that this question has been asked a number of times before.  I've spent a few hours working through the suggestions in previous answers but am still stuck.

I have installed Anaconda 1.9.7 and PyCharm 2019.2 on my Mac running Mojave version 10.14.5.

Through Conda 4.7.10 I have Python 3.7.3 and have pandas 0.25.0 installed.

When I create a new project in PyCharm and try to run the line:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Attempted solutions:

1. Have uninstalled and reinstalled PyCharm
2. Checked that all relevant programmes are installed and up to date
3. Checked the project interpreter is correct:

Conda Environment
Location: /Users/Barton/PyCharm/Get Pandas to Work
Python Version:  3.7
Conda executable:  /Users/Barton/anaconda3/bin/conda

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: Did you install pandas via this: `conda install -c anaconda pandas` ?

Comment: Pandas cam pre-installed with Anaconda Navigator.  Do I need to install through conda as well?  Thanks D

Comment: Give it a try, it's difficult to tell what your environment looks like/how it was installed in the first place

Comment: Ran: conda install -c anaconda pandas.  It did update and supersede a few packages.  Have recreated the conda environment but unfortunately still not working!  Still getting the original error message

Comment: Does the pandas package show within the pycharm project interpreter ?

Comment: I've just installed it through the Pycharm interpreter and now it works!!!  Brilliant - many thanks for your help.  Sorry to ask another question, but why did I need to do that?  Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, I didn't have to do it but I have not clue how your environment was setup so it's difficult to say.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I don't seem to be able to upvote your solution as it's in a comment?

Comment: Make my answer as correct, thanks :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Python, the best answer is to always use a virtual environment. You might fix this specific issue but later down the line, another import related issue may show up.

Answer (score 1):

Install it directly through the interpreter as no other solutions worked.

Comment: Yes, all the requirements are already satisfied.  The interpreter has been assigned